# Images not indexed by google since moving to cdn

Tags: seo, google, images, google-image-search

Last week I moved all the images on coffeeandvanilla.com to a cdn( maxcdn.coffeeandvanilla.com ).

The problem I'm having is that although the sitemap—generated by Yoast WordPress SEO plugin—points images to the correct location, Google only indexes[sic] images from the category and page site maps but 0 images from the posts sitemap( see screenshot https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4635252/sitemap.png )

This website has been doing quite well with Google image-search before the change, visits from Google image search have dropped from ~200/day to 11 yesterday

Here is an example entry from the generated posts.xml sitemap http://pastebin.com/vcMRf9VW

Can anyone suggest where the problem lies? Why have I lost all my google image juice? Should I just wait some more, how long before really worrying?

Comment: did you get this issue resolved? as I am in a position of 3000ish images submitted indexed 0 after doing exactly the same as you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried updating Yoast? It did have a rather nasty image sitemap bug:

> 1.2.8 Bug fixes: Fix for images not showing up in XML sitemap[1](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-cdn-images-in-sitemap#post-2944147).

EDIT: Final answer

I suspected that may be the case. I can't take any credit for this, but please find someone with the same problem and the resultant solution from the Yoast plugin creator:

> function wpseo_cdn_filter( $uri ) {
>       return str_replace( 'http://example.com', 'http://cdn.example.com', $uri );
>   }
>   add_filter( 'wpseo_xml_sitemap_img_src', 'wpseo_cdn_filter' );

[CDN Images in Sitemap](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-cdn-images-in-sitemap#post-2944147)

Comment: I'm using 1.2.8.7 The images show up in the sitemap correctly. The strange thing is that only images on the wordpress posts are failing to index, whilst others are fine.